# Good set for building several casual level decks

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I want to build several decks for casual playing. My plan is to choose a set, buy 6-7 of each common, 3 of each uncommon, maybe some cheap rares, a stack of basic lands plus whatever tokens I need and use this to build a deck for each single colour and for each pair of colours. As I have never played Magic a lot, I don't know the sets so choosing the set to build this from is hard for me.

I am looking for the following:

- coherent theme (I was thinking about Modern Horizons but cards from all over the place drove me off it)
- good availability (easy to buy, not very expensive, a lot of bulk rares)
- possibility to build 15 decks (mono and two colours) of similar power and playing differently, with all major Magic deck archetypes represented

Which set would you recommend for this?

Answer (score 1):

Core sets like M20 are pretty much built for this kind of "introductory" play, although if you want to represent EVERYTHING magic has to offer you might need to bleed across multiple core sets.

I'll also say that core sets tend not to have very much multi-colour support - Return to Ravnica springs to mind as a set that explicitly encourages dual-coloured deck building, if you're willing to branch out even further.

Comment: Core Sets utterly fail the "coherent theme" test, with Magic Origins being a partial exception.

Comment: M20 also had a lot of multicolour support, since it had all 10 of the life-gain taplands that could show up in the basic slot, Evolving Wilds at common, Scuttlemutt at uncommon and the 5 enemy-coloured temples at rare. Three-colour decks were very playable!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you are aware of this, but on Ebay you can buy a playset (4 of each) of all commons and uncommons of most any recent set as one purchase.  Price various depending on the set.  This will be much more economical than buying individual cards.

Comment: Yes, I know this and plan to get cards this way, although most likely via Cardmarket, not Ebay as it seems European traders use this website more and I definitely don't want to pay overseas shipping costs and risk getting cards stuck at customs.